# If statement between ulong and 0

Tags: c#, types, c#-3.0

Im trying to do this calculation but its trying to convert a ulong to an int to see if its less than 0. Ive tried getting rid of int and putting it before the 0 instead but its not working at all.

```
ulong a = -897324782938287523942985;
ulong b = 95;
if ((int)(a + (b * 10000)) < 0) 
{
 a += (b*10000)
} else {
 a += b;
}
```

which gives the error:

```
Exception trown: 'System.OverflowException' in mscorlib.dll
```

I need it to give me back a positive number just over 0 and below 95

Comment: `-897324782938287523942985 + 95 * 10000` is still huge negative number, I can't see why you should `if` when you can put it as `a += b * 10000;`. Are you going to implement a *loop*?

Answer (score 1):

It throws an exception because the value of `a` is invalid. `ulong` means Unsigned Long — it doesn't accept negative numbers. And value 897324782938287523942985 is **too big for all integer types in C#**.

*UPDATE*: `a` should be of type `double`. Firstly, it accepts negative numbers, and secondly, it accepts ***very big values*** — 897324782938287523942985 is valid for it.

Comment: I'd rather recommend `BigInteger` instead of `double`

Comment: That's weird though because I've been using it for negative numbers and its working?

Comment: @Yen I don't believe you used `ulong` for negative numbers. It's **_unsigned_**. @DmitryBychenko thanks for info, I didn't know about `BigInteger`.